# javascript word search with and without spaces from the start of the word

Tags: javascript, regex, search, full-text-search

I'm trying to write a search function that allows the user to input one of the following criteria to return 'ho chi minh city'. The tricky thing for me is it must always search for the **start** of any word. On top of this, it also has to work with other languages, but if i can get latin chars working that is at least a start.

```
                //ho chi minh city
                //hochiminhcity
                //chi minh
                //chiminh
                //chiminhcity
                //chi minh city
                //ho
                //chi
                //minh
                //city

            containsTerm: function containsTerm (needle, haystack) {

                var _this = LocationPickerCtrl,
                    ndl = _this.formatStr(stringHelper.escapeRegExp(needle)),
                    re = new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)' + ndl, 'gi'),
                    found = false,
                    len,
                    key = _this.formatStr(haystack.Key),
                    name = _this.formatStr(haystack.Name);

                //check airport code
                if (key.indexOf(ndl) > -1) {
                    found = true;
                }

                //start of word
                if (re.test(name)) {
                    found = true;
                }

                if (name.indexOf(' ') > -1) {

                    if (name.replace(/\s/g, '').indexOf(needle) === 0) {
                        found = true;
                    }

                }

return found

}
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: i've updated the comment to show you the function im writing, i think for me its easier to break it down

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see in time that you needed a regex :(

```
var words = ['ho', 'chi', 'minh', 'city'];

var hochiming = function hochiming(words, input) {

  var data = input;
  var match = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (data.length === 0) {
      return match;
    } else if (data.substring(0, words[i].length) === words[i]) {
      match = true;
      data = data.substring(words[i].length);
      if (data[0] === " ") {
        data = data.substring(1);
      }
    } else if (match) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return match;
}

var data = ['hochiminhcity', 'chi minh', 'chiminh', 'chiminhcity', 'chi minh city', 'ho', 'chi', 'minh', 'city'];
data.forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log('result:', hochiming(words, entry));
});

console.log('mistakes:');
(['ho chi minh ci', 'm aezfam', 'hochimineahcity', ' minhchi']).forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log('result:', hochiming(words, entry));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go the regex route, it could be done like this -

```
 # /(?=[hcm])(?:(?:ho)?\s*chi\s*minh(?:\s*city)?|(?:ho|chi|minh|city))/

 (?= [hcm] )                           # Start at a 'h', 'c', or 'm'
 (?:
      (?: ho )?                             # Optional 'ho'
      \s* chi \s* minh                      # Must have 'chi minh'
      (?: \s* city )?                       # Optional 'city'
   |                                      # or, 
      (?: ho | chi | minh | city )          # One of either 'ho','chi','minh', or 'city'
 )
```